# Unable to open terraform plan -out file from outside of Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Is it possible to open the file that's created when you run a `terraform plan -out`?

I've ran `terraform plan -out samplefile.txt` and would like to peruse the contents of the file but I'm unable to find a text editor capable of opening it.

Not sure if it's a character encoding issue.

Comment: It's a binary format that's only intended to be read by Terraform and passed to be used by the `apply` or `destroy` commands separately so they can check that nothing has changed since you accepted the plan. What are you trying to achieve here by reading the plan separately? You could convert the plan file into a JSON output by then running `terraform show -json plan.out > plan.json` (where `plan.out` is the outputted file from `terraform plan -out`) if that's what you need.

Comment: My reason for wanting to view the contents is I was reading about how Terraform matches the `serial number` in the state-file to the plan.out file as a means to track if changes have been made to the state by another operation after the plan was created.

And I was curious to see this.

Comment: If you are interested in it purely for curiosity and understanding, you might be interested to know that in Terraform v0.12 and v0.13 the plan file is a zip archive containing a few different artifacts: the prior state, the configuration, and a summary of the planned changes. You can save it with the `.zip` extension and inspect it using normal zip tools if you want, but keep in mind that it being a zip archive and the specific structure of the entries in the zip file are just an implementation detail of current Terraform versions and not something guaranteed to remain true in future releases.

Comment: Really interesting Martin. I did not know this before now. But saving the `-out` file as `.zip` has actually made things a whole lot clearer in terms of what goes on under the hood. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the [Terraform documentation for the `plan` command and its `-out` parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#out-path), this is meant to be used purely by Terraform so that the `apply` or `destroy` command will only do what the plan has determined. This prevents issues where something changes in your provider in between running the plan and then applying it which may cause Terraform to perform different, potentially destructive actions than had been shown during the plan stage.

The [Terraform internals documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/json-format.html) also covers how the binary output from `terraform plan -out` isn't meant to be directly read by other tools:

> When Terraform plans to make changes, it prints a human-readable
> summary to the terminal. It can also, when run with `-out=<PATH>`, write
> a much more detailed binary plan file, which can later be used to
> apply those changes.
>
> Since the format of plan files isn't suited for use with external
> tools (and likely never will be), Terraform can output a
> machine-readable JSON representation of a plan file's changes. It can
> also convert state files to the same format, to simplify data loading
> and provide better long-term compatibility.

If you want to view the contents of the plan file you can use the [`terraform show -json` command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/show.html).